# How to extract sequence elements wrapped in Option in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-option

I am learning Scala and struggling with `Option[Seq[String]]` object I need to process. There is a small array of strings `Seq("hello", "Scala", "!")` which I need to filter against `charAt(0).isUpper` condition.

Doing it on plain `val arr = Seq("hello", "Scala", "!")` is as easy as `arr.filter(_.charAt(0).isUpper)`. However, doing the same on `Option(Seq("hello", "Scala", "!"))` won't work since you need to call `.getOrElse` on it first. But even then how can you apply the condition?

`arr.filter(_.getOrElse(false).charAt(0).isUpper` is wrong. I have tried a lot of variants and searching stackoverflow didn't help either and I am wondering if this is at all possible. Is there an idiomatic way to handle `Option` wrapped cases in Scala?

Comment: `Some(Seq("hello", "Scala", "!")).map(seq => seq.filter(_.charAt(0).isUpper))` which can even be reduced to: `.map(seq => seq.filter(_(0).isUpper))`

Comment: you can always use a match case when you have Option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call foreach or map on the option, i.e. `arr.map(seq => seq.filter(_.charAt(0).isUpper))`

Comment: hmm, but is it good to use `foreach`? I assumed that it should be used in side effect methods only.

Comment: Right, well then just use map, that works on options too.

Comment: What? What is `.foreach.`?

Comment: I don't have a scala interpreter handy and it's been a while, so this is pseudocode :)

Comment: That's not pseudocode. That's wrong usage of `foreach`. The method `foreach` expects one function-valued argument. `.foreach.` is an attempt to invoke `foreach` with zero arguments. One is more than zero, I can tell you that much without an interpreter. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/

Comment: @AndreyTyukin thanks, updated. And cut me some slack here, it's been 3 years since I used Scala in my daily tasks :P

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply `f: X => Y` to a value `x` of type `X`, you write `f(x)`.

If you want to apply `f: X => Y` to a value `ox` of type `Option[X]`, you write `ox.map(f)`.

You seem to already know what you want to do with the sequence, so just put the appropriate `f` into `map`.

Example:

```
val ox = Option(Seq("hello", "Scala", "!"))

ox.map(_.filter(_(0).isUpper)) // Some(Seq("Scala"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *pattern matching* for that case as

```
Option(Seq("hello", "Scala", "!")) match {
      case Some(x) => x.filter(_.charAt(0).isUpper)
      case None => Seq()
    }
```

Comment: @AndreyTyukin thats something to return when Option returns None :)

Comment: I think that debugging code that returns `Seq("None")` might be just as fun as debugging large administrative legacy web-apps that fail to process people with [surname "Null"](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems) properly...

Comment: No, just change it to more natural choice `Seq()`, then it's fine imho ;)